# How to make a runnable JAR file that can read/write files?

Tags: java, file, file-io, jar, io

I have created a Java software with a graphical interface using SWING.  I have packaged it in a runneable JAR file by using he "export" function of ECLIPSE and it runs fine on my computer.

However, the function of reading files of my software does not work on some other computers.

I guess that it must be a security permission problem.

So my question is:  how to give the permissions to my Jar file or  how the user can give the permissions so that my software is allowed to read file?

I'm looking for something as simple as possible as i'm not going to sell my software.

EDIT: My application is a desktop application (not an applet).

Thanks,

Comment: An important bit of information to tell us: is the Jar being run as an applet on the other computers or is it a desk-top application such as a JFrame (or is it a web-start application)? This information will have big implications on the advice we give. For instance, if it's a desktop application, then security issues aren't usually a concern (with exceptions of course).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will be a desktop application.

Comment: Then the issue is not likely to be a security issue but rather a bug in your program. I think you'll need to show us code and any error messages. Are you trying to read "files" held in the jar file? If so, there's a problem there since jar files don't hold "files" but rather resources. Again, please tell us more. It's better to err on the side of telling us too much rather than not enough.

Comment: Also, how is your application finding the other files? Are you using a JFileChooser (which I recommend)?

Comment: Actually,  I just use a JFileChooser  showOpenDialog()  to ask which file to open.  On my computer it opens the file choosing window as it should.  On the other computer it does not.   I don't have the exception. But here is some part of the code: final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(path);
          fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(MainWindow.this);   But I don't think that this is the problem.

Comment: Please post code as an edit to your question rather than as a comment since code does not format well in comments. OK, what you should do is isolate the problem so you can work on just solving this problem and nothing else, no extraneous code. Consider trying to create a very small program that does nothing but uses a JFileChooser to say read and write a small file, try to jar it and run it elsewhere, and if still a problem, post the code in its entirety (an [sscce](http://sscce.org) here.

Comment: Or if it's not too big, post the whole thing on pastebin.

Comment: ok  first i will try to catch the exception.  and post the result

Comment: You didn't have any empty catch blocks did you?

Comment: No. Just that i did not output the errors. But i found the problem.... The problem was before the JFileChooser. I was with doing this for choosing the path:  URL main = MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class");
     if (!"file".equalsIgnoreCase(main.getProtocol()))
       throw new IllegalStateException("Main class is not stored in a file.");    On my computer it worked fine even from the Jar file. But on the other computer it did not work and threw the IllegalStateException.  THanks for your help.

Comment: no problem! Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Digitally sign the Jar.
2. Create an XML based ([JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info)) launch file for it.
3. Launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS can install desktop shortcuts & menu items for it, if requested in the launch file and supported on the target OS.

> I'm looking for something as simple as possible..

Installing applications in a way that is reliable & simple for the end user, is not easy for the developer.

Comment: Hey Andrew. Question: why digitally sign the jar if he's running it as a desktop application? /Pete

Comment: @Hover  Digital signature is necessary for points 2. (in which `all-permissions` will be declared) and 3. launching via. JWS.  Note that the symptoms suggest something entirely different to a basic permissions problem to me, since the OP mentioned it works on *some* other computers.  I suspect it has more to do with the JRE version installed, though the OP's replies to your request of an SSCCE will likely reveal more.  Of course, if using JWS, it is possible to launch the app. sand-boxed and use the JNLP API services to access the file-system, but that would require some code changes.